# How do i place submit button at the bottom of page

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

fieldset {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <fieldset class="border">
      <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2">Subject Name</legend>
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" style="box-shadow: none" name="name" placeholder="Subject Name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="border">
      <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2">Author</legend>
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" style="box-shadow: none" name="author" placeholder="Subject Name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="border">
      <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2">For Grade</legend>
      <select name="for" id="" class="form-control border-0 " style="box-shadow: none">

        <option value="">
          Test
        </option>

      </select>

    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center w-100 ">Add</button>
</form>
```

[this is my view. I want to place add button at the bottom of this page. mt-auto doesn't work, I have tried position fixed-but it doesn't make responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCY7r.png)

Comment: Hey @Mr.Bil can you post your html to test it in a fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

Add to css code:

```
button{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

On every Bootstrap page you must start with a foundation and build with certain BS classes. The following is a skeleton of the working example:

```html
<!--PATTERN: -----------------------------------------.container-->
<form class='container'>
  <!--.tall is a custom class see example-->
  <!------------------------------------------------.row-->
  <section class="row tall">
    <!--------------------------------------------.col-->
    <fieldset class="col"> </fieldset>
    <!--------------------------------------------.col-->  
    <fieldset class="col"> </fieldset>
    <!--------------------------------------------.col-->
    <fieldset class="col"> </fieldset>
  </section>

  <!------------------------------------------------.row-->
  <section class='row'>
    <!--------------------------------------------.col-->
    <button class="col">Add</button>
  </section>

</form>
```

The most basic BS pattern is:

- `.container` wraps around everything
- `.row` is directly under `.container` and is like a table row stretching edge to edge of `.container`.
- `.col` is directly under `.row`. Each sibling of `.col` should be another `.col` and they will sit next to each other just like table cells do.
- content should go in each `.col`

```css
.tall {
  min-height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class='container' action="" method="post">
  <section class="row form-group tall">
    <fieldset class="border col">
      <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2">Subject Name</legend>
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" style="box-shadow: none" name="name" placeholder="Subject Name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="border col">
      <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2">Author</legend>
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" style="box-shadow: none" name="author" placeholder="Subject Name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="border col">
      <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2">For Grade</legend>
      <select name="for" id="" class="form-control border-0 " style="box-shadow: none">

        <option value="">
          Test
        </option>

      </select>

    </fieldset>
  </section>
  <section class='row'>
  <button type="submit" class="col btn btn-primary text-center w-100 ">Add</button>
  </section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div class="form-group " style="min-height:80vh">
    <fieldset class="border">
      <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2">Subject Name</legend>
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" style="box-shadow: none" name="name" placeholder="Subject Name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="border">
      <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2">Author</legend>
      <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" style="box-shadow: none" name="author" placeholder="Subject Name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="border">
      <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2">For Grade</legend>
      <select name="for" id="" class="form-control border-0 " style="box-shadow: none">

        <option value="">
          Test
        </option>

      </select>

    </fieldset>
    </div>
   <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary ">Add</button>
```

i did this and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).